# Getting error a reference to System.Net.Http could not be added while adding 'System.Net.Http' on .net

Tags: c#, .net

When i try to add **'System.Net.Http'** manually my .net project throw an error

> A reference to 'System.Net.Http' could not be added

i try to restore the nuget packages but still getting this error unable to understand.